# Kotlin - custom Exception as data class?

Tags: exception, kotlin

In Kotlin, it's extremely easy to create custom exceptions. Below is a sample that accepts `code` as an argument:

`class PortraitRequestFailedException(val code: Int) : RuntimeException()`

The `code` contains the http response error code returned from the server. The problem is, when that exception is reported generically by a logger, like `Timber.e(exception, "Error loading portrait cover photo url")`, the `code` is lost in the output:

```
2020-02-14 13:50:59.886 15942-16232 E/PortraitManager$watchCoverPhotoUrl: Error loading portrait cover photo url
    com.example.data.PortraitManager$PortraitRequestFailedException
        at com.example.data.PortraitManager$loadCoverPhotoUrl$1.call(PortraitManager.kt:139)
```

Of course I could add a `when exception is PortraitRequestFailedException` clause and handle specifically that particular error, but I don't want that (especially that all exceptions in Kotlin are unchecked and I may not be aware what type to expect).

I've found an easy way to pass the code to a `RuntimeException` as the `message` parameter:

`class PortraitRequestFailedException(val code: Int) : RuntimeException(code.toString())`

```
2020-02-14 13:40:32.878 430-857 E/PortraitManager$watchCoverPhotoUrl: Error loading portrait cover photo url
    com.example.data.PortraitManager$PortraitRequestFailedException: 403
        at com.example.data.PortraitManager$loadCoverPhotoUrl$1.call(PortraitManager.kt:139)
```

But that approach looks a bit too verbose to me (I need to reference the `code` in the parent class constructor), and it will just print `PortraitRequestFailedException: 403`, not telling what 403 refers to (imagine having more than one argument here).

So I came up with an idea of defining my custom exception as a data class:

`data class PortraitRequestFailedException(val code: Int) : RuntimeException()`

Since data classes in Kotlin have an auto-generated `toString()` method in a form of `PortraitRequestFailedException(code=403)`, such notation has all the advantages I want, without added verbosity or boilerplate code. The log is the following:

```
E/PortraitManager$watchCoverPhotoUrl: Error loading portrait cover photo url
    PortraitRequestFailedException(code=403)
        at com.example.data.PortraitManager$loadCoverPhotoUrl$1.call(PortraitManager.kt:139)
```

Do you see any drawbacks of such an approach? Are there any dangers of handling exceptions as data classes?

Comment: The only drawback is that you can't inherit from data class

Answer (score 0):

I'd slightly lean for manually overriding `toString()` yourself as that's the only thing you need of a `data class`. 
But overall it works, and has no significant drawbacks, really.